# 7490 Counting But a Little bit Buggy

Tags: 555, counter

I followed a video [(Click Here)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq3AoUZztrs) to make the 0-9 Counter.
The counter does work but its a little bit buggy.

For the first 0 - 9 cycle it works fine but then it starts to follow this sequence:
[image]

Where is the bug being caused?

---

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

4 5 6 Are bugging then they fix and move on.
p.s Im Using a 9Volt Battery

Comment: Show us your circuit.

Comment: You can press ctrl-m while editing to bring up a schematic editor. It'll be a lot easier to help you if you show what you have.

Comment: "Im Using a 9Volt Battery"- are you powering the ICs through a 5V regulator, or directly from the 9V battery? Most Logic ICs are designed for 5V or less and may blow up over 7V. If you don't have a regulator then use a 6V battery (eg. 4 x AA cells). www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn5447a

Comment: Well. They be working fine with 9V. None of them blew up yet...

Comment: Unless these ICs are CMOS, please use the ICs at 5 volts. The switching transients as the 4 internal flipflops switch is upsetting the VDD and causing the 8-9-0-1 state machine to misbehave. Again....run at 5 volts, with 0.1uF across pin 8-16.

Comment: Bipolar TTL logic parts (7490, 74LS90, etc.) MUST be operated from a 5 Volt (+/-10%) power supply.  The parts may misbehave or be damaged if you attempt to operate them from 9 volts.

Comment: Do you have any decoupling caps for the ICs?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have some kind of wiring error, or perhaps a floating input if you are using CMOS parts. Assuming you're using a 74x47 decoder-driver.

The 7447 family are not fully decoded so if you feed a number greater than 0x1001 to them they will show something that may look odd.

[image]

Edit: If the wiring is fine then you most likely have a power issue. Make sure you have a 0.1uF ceramic bypass capacitor very near the 7490 power and ground pins. Try reducing the display current by 10:1 and see if the issue goes away (you can put a series resistor in the anode just for a test- the segments will be uneven but it's easier than changing all 7 resistors).

Bad debouncing should not cause this issue because those counts should never come up if the counter is working properly. If you can stop it when it is displaying an invalid digit, test the inputs with a meter and see what they read.

Edit2: You seem to have no resistors in the segment lines. This is very bad and can damage your display or driver chip. It also can upset the supply causing your problem. Try about 500 ohms in each line (7 resistors)- eg. 470 ohms or 560 ohms. Also you MUST have a 0.1uF or higher ceramic capacitor from Vdd to GND and it should be near the 7490 (a couple cm at most). And another across the 555 power. And tie unused inputs to GND or to +5 through 1K (74xx) or directly (all other types such as 74LSxx).

Comment: Yes. I am using a 7447. The wiring is correct, since I rechecked it.What should I do to overcome this error?

Comment: Schematic updated.

Comment: I'm a novice, can't really understand your point with the resistors. Can you please elaborate. Thanks :)

Comment: You need a resistor in each segment line! Try 500 ohms or so.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved Such designs already exist - e.g. see here http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/bcd-counter-circuit.html. To summarize everything said before me: you should have all LS90 inputs connected (do not keep them floating), do not forget to connect its GND and VCC, use +5 V +-10% power. Looking to values you drawn I would say you have bit 3 stuck for some reason (0,1,2,3,12[8+4],13[8+5],4,5,14[8+6],6,7,8,9). Do you have 12 and 13 *instead* of 4 and 5, or these states *are followed* by 4 and 5 (making counter counting 13 states instead of 10)?

Comment: @Anonymous With no bypass caps and no segment resistors to limit the LED current and open inputs it's no wonder he's getting flaky operation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are counting in HEX (16) when you want to count in DEC (10) or 0~9

Review the datasheet to see what connections are needed to reset to 0 on the next negative input edge after 9.

- Note 1: Output QA is connected to input B for BCD count.
- ensure this is connected.

ALso if using CMOS 74HC90 terminate unused inputs correctly 0 or 1.

Comment: im not counting in HEX, since it goes to 0-9 then again 0 - 9 but sometimes i receive a floating number

Comment: the symbols you show are only generated in non DEC numbers, therefore your _In_B  feedback signal is "sometimes" wrong.  Check your Vdd for stability  and check the signal on _In_B pin.  That is the only logical explanation other than EMI, lack of decoupling cap., excessive supply droop from lack of segment R's.  CHECK AGAIN... THIS IS a HEX  decoded symbol.